# C# Inheritance of variables and its modification

Tags: c#, inheritance, enums

I have the following Control abstract class where some common variables, fields and methods are defined. ClickState is an emum type. Then I derive the button class where I do not override the Update method since I don't need any additional behaviour, so I use the base one.

```
public abstract class Control
{ 
private ClickState _clickState;

   public Control()
   {
      _clickState = CliskState.Start;
   }

   public virtual void Update()
   {
      if(***some check if mouse is over the control***)
        {
          _clickstate = ClickState.MouseOver;
        }
   }
}

public class Button : Control
{
///other code
}
```

...

```
b = new Button();
```

every frame:

```
b.Update();
```

Now, when I mouse over my button the check in the Update method (called every frame) actually works but somehow the _clickState variable does not change. If I put a breakpoint in the code after the assignment I see that the _clickState variable of the Control class changed but the one in Button did not... I am conused, I tought that  the Button._clickState should be the same of its "mother" class Control since is inherited. Is the issue with some access modifier?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Do you add a "new" `_clickState` field to `Button`? THat's the only way I can see having separate fields for `Button` and `Control`.

Comment: No I did not use new. So I guess I should only have 1 _clickState variable. It is just defined in the base class.

Comment: Correct. You should have gotten a warning about the field "hiding" the base class field. So the base class field is being set, not the child class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your understanding is correct and I believe your code works correct also.
Or you didn't show some piece of code that may do some changes.

Be sure you don't have another **_clickState** field in your Button class.

Here is my version of your code: https://dotnetfiddle.net/OKdSnj

Try to add console output inside of your IF statement to see all values in real-time - it might help you to troubleshoot.

```
    if(/*some check if mouse is over the control*/)
    {
        _clickState = ClickState.MouseOver;
        // Try to add console output to see all values here
        Console.WriteLine($"New state: {_clickState}");
    }
```

Comment: yes I tried to do console.writeline(_clickedState) and it outputs the variable just changed 1 line above. But I believe that way I am reading from the base class and somehow not from the instance of the Button.

Comment: Yes sorry for wasting your time. I checkeed again the code and somehow (maybe in a copy cut situation) the _clickState variable vas definded in both classes... so I was changing only one.
Sorry.

Comment: Maybe you can try modify fiddle I send before, so we can reproduce your issue.